# How to write this MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, logic

Suppose we have a table `Users` that has only one column `UserId` which is the primary key.

We have a second table `Events` that has three columns, `EventId`, `UserId` and `Status`. A `Status` is a `BOOL NOT NULL`. `UserId` is indexed but not unique.

The table `Status` has the foreign key constraint `UserId` on `Users.UserId`.

Now I want to query all the `UserId`s for which there is no row in `Events` such that `Event.Status = TRUE`. Is there a way to do this with `JOIN`? (One statement only preferred)

For example:

```
Users
--------
1
2
3

Events
--------
EventId   UserId  Status
1         1       FALSE
2         1       TRUE
3         2       FALSE
4         2       FALSE
```

Then the query I'm looking for should return:

```
UserId
-------
2
3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, a subselect is a [reasonably efficient](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) way to do this on MySQL. So:

```
SELECT UserId
FROM   Users
WHERE  UserId NOT IN (
       SELECT DISTINCT UserID
       FROM   Events
       WHERE  Status = TRUE
       )
```

Note that I'm using `DISTINCT` there, which may not be a perfect fit for the referenced article. Mind you, you may be fine with `DISTINCT`, or with leaving it off (but I don't know whether that would result in a problematic interim data set, or if MySQL is smart about it).

Or you can do the LEFT JOIN / IS NULL version, which doesn't have the `DISTINCT` issue:

```
SELECT    Users.UserId
FROM      Users
LEFT JOIN Events
          ON Events.UserId = Users.UserId AND Events.Status = TRUE
WHERE     Events.UserId IS NULL
```

See the link above for a discussion, but MySQL provides basically the same performance in both cases (whereas using `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN` would be markedly less efficient).

I'd try both (or all three, if you try both with and without `DISTINCT` on the first one) and see what performs best with your real-life data.

Comment: The Left join seems to be a better option. The first option uses DISTINCT which can impact performance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521055/in-sql-how-does-using-distinct-affect-performance

Comment: @isobar: Good point, the article referenced isn't using DISTINCT, and the performance characteristics will be different with it there.

Comment: Thanks! You guys are awesome! =) In fact, fortunately in the actual scenario the table will only ever have one TRUE per UserId.

Comment: Wait a second. Why did it matter whether DISTINCT was used?

Comment: `DISTINCT` carries performance overhead because MySQL has to ensure that only distinct values are included in the data set (probably by using a sort-then-collapse algorithm or similar), whereas without it, it can just append any matching value it finds to the data set, which is quicker. In your case, if there can only be 0 or 1 entries with `Status = TRUE` in `Entries`, you don't need `DISTINCT` and so don't have to worry and can leave it off. Even if there could be more values/UserId, unless there were a large number, you'd probably be fine without it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select UserId
from Users
where UserId not in (
    select UserId 
    from Events 
    where Status = TRUE)
```

With left join:

```
select UserId
from Users usr
    left join Events evt on
        evt.UserId = usr.UserId and evt.Status = TRUE
where evt.UserId is null
```

Comment: Hmm... I can't tick two Answers? Well both of you are correct :)

Comment: @javic - I was the first one :).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - fair enough :). Let the answer be yours :). I could offer reference materials too. I believe this wasn't asked in the question. Was just answering the question.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize so. Peace :)